# Clicking dynamically created buttons jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a jQuery datatable where each row has an add to cart button. If I perform a search or I click on another entry of pages in the table, the table will dynamically load new rows & buttons. Therefore, I have two types of add to cart buttons - one for the dynamically created buttons and one for the original buttons:

Click event for dynamically created buttons:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn.btn-primary.addtocart', function() {
    //add to cart
});
```

Click event for original buttons:

```
$(".addtocart").click(function() {
    //add to cart
});
```

The problem I'm having is if I click the original buttons, the click event fires twice. Does anyone know of a strategy or work around for this?

Comment: Could you show a bit of how the HTML looks like?

Comment: why do you need 2 handlers for existing and dynamic one's, are they different logically

Comment: because the dynamic buttons dont work with the original handlers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) in the button click handler to stop event from bubbling.

```
$(".addtocart").click(function (event) {
    //                          ^^^^^    Pass event object to the callback
    //add to cart

    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

If both the handlers are same, I'll suggest to use only a delegated handler for both dynamic and static elements.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn.btn-primary.addtocart', function () {
    // add to cart
});
```

Comment: Gotcha - I am using chrome right now. Does that work for IE, Firefox, & Safari?

Comment: @user1547174 Yes, it should work. That also depends on the browser version and version of jQuery you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It is a easy solution.

Just use on method in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("dynamically_created_element_selector").on("click", function()
    {
        //do whatever u want
    });
});
```

### Demo is here-

```js
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        var r= $('<br/><button class="dynamic_button" type="button">Dynamic Button</button>');
        $("body").append(r);
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', 'button.dynamic_button', function ()
    {
        alert("Dynamic Element Clicked !!");
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <button>Insert after</button> 
</body>
```

Comment: Yes - I have that right now. The problem is the dynamic handler and the original handler BOTH fire whereas I only want one of them to fire. Tushar's answer below solved my problem.